# How modify VB.Net code for save webpages as mht automatically?

Tags: html, vb.net, mhtml

I have a simple VB.Net program for saving webpages as `mht` format
currently I'm using the following way:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    WebBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.google.com")
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim SaveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
    SaveFileDialog1.Filter = "mht files (*.mht)|*.mht|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    If SaveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        fileNamePath = SaveFileDialog1.FileName
        SavePage(WebBrowser1.Url.ToString, fileNamePath)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub SavePage(ByVal Url As String, ByVal FilePath As String)
    Dim iMessage As CDO.Message = New CDO.Message
    iMessage.CreateMHTMLBody(Url, CDO.CdoMHTMLFlags.cdoSuppressObjects, "", "")
    Dim adodbstream As ADODB.Stream = New ADODB.Stream
    adodbstream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeText
    adodbstream.Charset = "UTF-8"
    adodbstream.Open()
    iMessage.DataSource.SaveToObject(adodbstream, "_Stream")
    adodbstream.SaveToFile(FilePath, ADODB.SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateOverWrite)
End Sub
```

My code work fine, but the save process is like a normal save page in a browser. **Right-Click > Save page as ... and select a direction with a name for saving file**

Is there a way that save operation to be performed automatically? without any popup windows, just give the program a direction and a file name in the code

for example :

```
 SavePage("http://google.com", "C:\google.mht")
```

this code didn't work and i have error `Write to file failed.` for the following code

```
adodbstream.SaveToFile(FilePath, ADODB.SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateOverWrite)
```

Comment: yeah...just comment out the code that creates the dialog box. However, all pages will get saved to the same location.

Comment: if i will remove that, what about file name and the path ? @Jeremy

Comment: fileNamePath is set by the dialog. just hard code your string like you have in the sample of how you wanted to call the function.

Comment: didn't work . `error : can not write to file` @Jeremy

Comment: change your question to show how you modified the code

Comment: Try with `ADODB.SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateNotExist`

Comment: i tried this too , didn't work @Hackerman

Answer (score 1):

```
Imports ADODB
Imports CDO
Public Class Form1
    Dim fileNamePath = "C:\"

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(TextBox1.Text)
    End Sub

    Private Sub SavePage(ByVal Url As String, ByVal FilePath As String)
        Try
            Dim iMessage As CDO.Message = New CDO.Message
            iMessage.CreateMHTMLBody(Url, CDO.CdoMHTMLFlags.cdoSuppressObjects, "", "")
            Dim adodbstream As ADODB.Stream = New ADODB.Stream
            adodbstream.Type = ADODB.StreamTypeEnum.adTypeText
            adodbstream.Charset = "UTF-8"
            adodbstream.Open()
            iMessage.DataSource.SaveToObject(adodbstream, "_Stream")
            adodbstream.SaveToFile(FilePath & CheckAndClean(TextBox1.Text) & ".mht", ADODB.SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateOverWrite)

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
           End Sub
    Private Function CheckAndClean(ByVal StringToCheck As String) As String
        Dim sIllegal As String = "\,/,:,*,?," & Chr(34) & ",<,>,|"
        Dim arIllegal() As String = Split(sIllegal, ",")
        Dim sReturn As String
        sReturn = StringToCheck
        For i = 0 To arIllegal.Length - 1
            sReturn = Replace(sReturn, arIllegal(i), "")
        Next
        Return sReturn
    End Function
    Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted
        SavePage(TextBox1.Text, fileNamePath)
    End Sub
```

Comment: Oh my God :| forget these ways please. I tried all of them. Help me solve that error

Comment: Look at end of my post

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do not understand my question @mysta

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
adodbstream.SaveToFile(FilePath & "Filename.mht", ADODB.SaveOptionsEnum.adSaveCreateOverWrite)
```

Comment: What the problem? Worked for me, i tested.

Comment: i don't know ... i can't understand the problem of my code

Comment: I don't understand your problem, you want one click save this page? from textbox address?